# netlogo How to count total number of turtles within some distance

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to control the moving speed of turtles base on the population of its area. My problem is that how to count total number of turtles that have a distance smaller than 3 with current turtle, and store this number into a new variable?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `in-radius` primitive in the NetLogo dictionary. Most likely you will want a command similar to `ask turtles [ set varname count turtles in-radius 3 ]`